# How we can make our Android app use less amount of battery

Tags: android

we have developed an android app. that's take more battery when this app is installed in our phone. we have use google play service in our APP permanently. because our application is based on location app.

Comment: Use battery historian to find areas of your app which are consuming battery and correct those areas

Comment: @AnuraagBaishya basically our problem in below android 5.0. how we use battery historian in below android 5.0.

Answer (score 0):

Location app means you are using GPS right .It may perform many background processes. Battery consumption varies from device to device. Test your app on different devices with different versions

Comment: you are right to Battery consumption varies device to device. but we want to make our Application drain less amount of battery. if you have any idea please share me.

Comment: @shubhamkumarsharma Use Evernote Josbscheduler library to access location.You can see the results.

Answer (score 0):

For battery optimization in your app you can use tools like Profile GPU rendering speed  Battery Historian.

Also follow these approaches to not let your app drain battery :

- Use GPS only when you need it,
- Use alarm manager carefully, as it drains a lot of battery,
- Use JobScheduler API, to optimize jobs, 
  this API schedules jobs in well optimized way, in application's own process.
- Avoid network call and wake lock as much as possible.